# Error when configuring lspconfig with mason

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp, mason

I'm trying to set up autocompletion, fixing, etc. for lua files in Neovim. I started by trying to follow the instructions from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpQMeFph1RE&t=188s

However, I quickly found out that sumneko_lua no longer exists so I replaced it with lua_ls. Here is my lazy config:

```
{'williamboman/mason.nvim', config = function() require("mason").setup() end},
{
    'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
    config = function() 
        require("mason-lspconfig").setup({ensure_installed = {'lua_ls'}})
    end,
    dependencies = {'williamboman/mason.nvim'}},
{
    'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
    dependencies = {'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim', 'williamboman/mason.nvim'},
    config = function() 
        require('lspconfig').lua_ls.setup({})
    end
}
```

However, when I launch Neovim I see the following error:

> Failed to run `config` for nvim-lspconfig
> ...share/nvim/lazy/nvim-lspconfig/lua/lspconfig/configs.lua:10:
> attempt to index local 'config_def' (a boolean value)

I'm confused by this error, since I am not calling anything by the name of `config_def`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could be a bug in the plugin

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the name of `lua_ls` in `lspconfig` is still `sumneko_lua`. So replacing this worked:

```
{'williamboman/mason.nvim', config = function() require("mason").setup() end},
{
    'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
    config = function() 
        require("mason-lspconfig").setup({ensure_installed = {'lua_ls'}})
    end,
    dependencies = {'williamboman/mason.nvim'}},
{
    'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
    dependencies = {'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim', 'williamboman/mason.nvim'},
    config = function() 
        -- HERE'S THE BIT I HAD TO CHANGE:
        require('lspconfig').sumneko_lua.setup({})
    end
}
```

My guess is that mason has updated the name to `lua_ls` but `lspconfig` hasn't.